# Magento 2 Short array syntax is not allowed while Module testing.

Tags: magento2, testing, array, coding-standards

Magento 2 module testing tools gives error "short array syntax not allowed",

we do code like following

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('Disable')],
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Enable')],

        ];
    }
```

Here is screenshot

[image]

Can any one tell me how can i solve this?

Comment: which php version you are using ?

Comment: i use 7.0.24 php version.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the Marketplace coding standard enforces the old long array syntax `array()` instead of `[]` for historic reasons.

You have three options:

- ignore the "error"
- accept the coding standard and use the long array syntax (I wouldn't recommend)
- try your luck with a pull request to remove the outdated rule:

  `magento/marketplace-ecg`: https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp/blob/master/MEQP2/ruleset.xml#L69-L72

In the Magento repository itself it is already the other way around: the short array syntax is enforced: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/Arrays/ShortArraySyntaxSniff.php